# How to get Footer value of infragistics UltraWebGrid Using Java Script

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I set footer for Ultrawebgrid   and its working Fine. But for some other uses i need to access the footer Value of ultrawebgrid . So i need to know how to get footer value of ultrawebgrid by using java script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the column and that can be used to get the text of the footer with the getFooterText method.

For example:

```
var grid = igtbl_getGridById(gridName);
var text = grid.Bands[0].Columns[2].getFooterText();
```

You may want to review the [Client Side Object Model](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_CSOM.html) in the documentation as well.